# How to I get an invalid time value with javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="time" title="Start Time" id="txtStartTime" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 75px"/>
```

I want to accept this(--:--) as valid but I don't want to accept this (exp 12:--) as valid. I can't control it because it gets nan value in both

Comment: The whole point of using an `input` with `type="time"` is to prevent invalid times from being entered.

Comment: Well how do I activate required in windows(dialog) open with javascript?

Comment: Instead of setting up an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you trying to do that you think requires an invalid date?

Comment: `document.getElementById("txtStartTime").valueAsNumber = NaN` might do

Comment: I want to accept this(--:--) as valid but I don't want to accept this (exp 12:--) as valid. I can't control it because it gets nan value in both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that JavaScript translates any incomplete time input into an empty string, both `(--:--)` and `(12:--)` will have the value of an empty string when they are read for processing.

So, there is no possible way you can differentiate them.

Possible option are to take the input in formats other than time input, plain text for example.